# Multiple Dynamic Meters - Adequate GUI Library?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

since I am fairly new to Java development and don't have much time, I'd thought I ask around if you have any ideas for this:

I want to display a user multiple vertical bars or meters where each bar represents the current state value of each member of a group. These values are updated in real time. I would like it to look something like this (only vertical of course):

*Bar Example 1:*

[image: Bar Example 1]

*Bar Example 2:*

[image: Bar Example 2]

Would anyone happen to know if there is a nice GUI library out there that would let me implement something like it quickly? This is part of a larger software in which we are using Swing, so that might be a dependency...

Comment: Use a [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) ..

Comment: What he ^^^^ said. And if this is changing "in real time" then hopefully you already know about use of background threading and Swing applications. A SwingWorker would work well here.

Comment: _"quickly"_ is relative, but [tag:jfreechart] works well for this; the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) shows several relevant examples.